# How to do a select and be able to fall back to default values?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hopefully I am asking this question clearly....if not please tell me and I will revise promptly.

This questions revolves around my account settings table (account_data)...essentially if an account has an entry in the table then the setting is defined...if it doesn't then I need to load the default value (account_id is null). Table structure :

```
     CREATE TABLE `account_data` (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `account_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `created` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
     UNIQUE KEY `account_id_name` (`account_id`,`name`) USING BTREE,
     KEY `account_id` (`account_id`)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

A quick note : account_id could be (not decided) a foreign key to account table, id column.

Example data set :

```
account_id | name | value
null | email_allowed | 0
1 | email_allowed | 1
null | persist_login | 0
null | homepage_version | small
```

So currently I am doing the following to get a single setting value for an account...

```
     SELECT * FROM account_data WHERE `name` = :name AND (account_id = :account_id OR account_id IS NULL) ORDER BY account_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

This seems to work fine...if it is not a good idea for any reason I would love to hear why. However when I need to get all account_data values for a single account I am doing two queries....

```
    SELECT * FROM account_data WHERE account_id = :account_id
```

and

```
    SELECT * FROM account_data WHERE account_id is null
```

and then merging them in my code....is there a way to do this with only one query?

Comment: What is the need to pull account_id = null, something is wrong in your logic

Comment: null `acount_id`s are default values

Comment: create an array with the key/value pairs for the default values. Retrieve the values from the database and overwrite the array only with those data returned from the db

Comment: TheWildHealer is correct, that is how I store my default values currently (can change).  Lelio Faieta, that is how I am doing it currently

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be to create a new column containing the default value by joining the table over itself:

```
select
    ad1.account_id,
    ad2.name,
    ad1.value as accountValue,
    ad2.value as defaulValue
from
    account_data ad1 outer join
    account_data ad2 on (
        ad1.name = ad2.name and 
        ad1.account_id = :account_id and 
        ad2.account_id is null
    )
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ad2.account_id IS null`? Using equals should not work with null

Comment: yes, and there's more to that, my query won't return the name and other fields for records that only have a default value, I'll fix it rn

Comment: Done, should return expected results now.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks, I appreciate this clever approach.  Could I get your opinion if this worth the added complexity/overhead verse just doing the process in my code?

Comment: And you could use `COALESCE` to determine which setting value to use...

Comment: Depends of your code (language, framework), although with one query, data only transits once between your database and the backend. This will speed up the process especially if your database is on a different server as the backend*

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is that you don't have all the settings.  If not all are defaults, then this is a bit tricker.

How about a prioritization query?

```
select a.*
from account_data a
where account_id = :account_id
union all
select a.*
from account_data a
where account_id is null and
      not exists (select 1
                  from account_data ad2
                  where ad2.name = ad.name and
                        ad2.account_id = :account_id
                 );
```

This should get all defaults (that don't match) plus all setting for the account).

Comment: So, we have a rule that all settings will have a default value.  I also am willing to have a "settings" table that stores either just the settings or the default values as well.  Do you think either of these changes would produce a better sql query?  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @hendr1x . . . I'm not sure what you mean by "better".  This should work well, particularly with indexes on `account_data(account_id)` and `account_data(name, account_id)`.

Comment: By better I mean faster performance (query time, resources used) and simpler, easier to maintain code.  I understand this might be a bit of an opinion based question but I thought it was worth asking.